# How to get to previous deployment in truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, metamask

So I deployed an application twice. But i just want to make changes to first one. So how to do that? This is my summary:

```
Summary
    =======
    > Total deployments:   2
    > Final cost:          0.003708932511868584 ETH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EVM bytecode is immutable by design. Once you deploy a contract, you cannot change its implementation.

You can change the source code, re-compile it, and then deploy it to a new address. Note that the newly deployed contract **does not** hold the storage values of the previous one.